# cache played data on exoplayer

Tags: android, caching, mpeg-dash, exoplayer

I write an android application for streaming video in MPEG-DASH protocol..
I'm using Exoplayer and for now I test on [the demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo)

I read some questions on stackoverflow and issues on exoplayer and write this code for cache a video

in DashRendererBuilder(in demo):

```
Cache cache = new SimpleCache(context.getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 10));
  // Build the video renderer.
  DataSource videoDataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);
  CacheDataSource videoCacheDataSource= new CacheDataSource(cache, videoDataSource, false, false);
  ChunkSource videoChunkSource= new DashChunkSource(manifestFetcher,
      DefaultDashTrackSelector.newVideoInstance(context, true, filterHdContent),
          videoCacheDataSource, new AdaptiveEvaluator(bandwidthMeter), LIVE_EDGE_LATENCY_MS,
      elapsedRealtimeOffset, mainHandler, player);//*/
  ChunkSampleSource videoSampleSource = new ChunkSampleSource(videoChunkSource, loadControl,
      VIDEO_BUFFER_SEGMENTS * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE, mainHandler, player,
      DemoPlayer.TYPE_VIDEO);
  TrackRenderer videoRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(context, videoSampleSource,
      MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT, 5000, drmSessionManager, true,
      mainHandler, player, 50);

  //cache audio
  Cache cache2 = new SimpleCache(context.getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 4));

  // Build the audio renderer.
  DataSource audioDataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);
  CacheDataSource audioCacheDataSource= new CacheDataSource(cache2, audioDataSource, false, false);
  ChunkSource audioChunkSource = new DashChunkSource(manifestFetcher,
      DefaultDashTrackSelector.newAudioInstance(), audioCacheDataSource, null, LIVE_EDGE_LATENCY_MS,
      elapsedRealtimeOffset, mainHandler, player);
  ChunkSampleSource audioSampleSource = new ChunkSampleSource(audioChunkSource, loadControl,
      AUDIO_BUFFER_SEGMENTS * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE, mainHandler, player,
      DemoPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO);
  TrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(audioSampleSource,
      drmSessionManager, true, mainHandler, player, AudioCapabilities.getCapabilities(context));
```

the problem is when I seek forward on the cached data it works well. but seems when I seek backward on the played data, data is lose and download vide again.

how I can fix this? for example I want to cache the last two minute or cache all the played data same as how youtube works when it uses html5.